Equivariant Riemannian metrics on homogeneous spaces
Let $G$ be a compact Lie group and $K$ a closed subgroup. The quotient $M = G/K$ is a homogeneous manifold and we would like to endow it with a $G$-equivariant Riemannian metric. It should be that any such metric is given by a $K$-equivariant inner product on the tangent space of the identity coset that can then be "moved around" $M$ smoothly by the group action. This should mean that metrics are $\mathbb{C}^X$-parameterised by the number of irreducible $K$-submodules of the $K$-module $T_e$. Is this correct?
Edit: In response to Thomas' comment, let me additionally assume that $T_e$ decomposes into a multiplicity-free direct sum of $K$-modules. Then the "number" of summand makes sense.

You should be carefull with the term "number" : let $K={e}$, what do you mean exactly ?

@Thomas: Thanks for the comment. I have edited my question to remove the ambiguity.

t hen the answer is simple : for each irreducible component you have only 1 invariant positive definite quadratic form, up to a positive scalar. Tne set of metrics is a convex cone of dimension the number of irreducible factors.
